# Thermodynamics- How are various property tables made?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I've always been curious about how different thermodynamic property tables are made. It's really interesting to me. I want to know how different things such as critical properties and variations of properties of different substances are determined. I'm not familiar with statistical physics, but any derivations using it would be great for future reference.

Comment: How would you react if I was asking you : I would like to learn the History of England, or  the geometry, or the laws of my country. What should I do ?

Comment: @Maurice Recommend some books.

Comment: Books about what ? Are you looking for books about (I copy your second line)  "different things such as properties and variations of properties of different systems" ? Well ! What does it mean, apart from ... all our scientific knowledges ?

Comment: @Maurice I meant different substances.

Comment: Today the number of known substances is greater than 10 millions, and is increasing every day.

Comment: Property tables are made by a bunch of lab slaves repeating the same experiments with different compounds and tabulating the results. Sometimes, the experiment is essentially decentralised because any individual who synthesises a compound will routinely measure a property which then just needs to be aggregated by CAS or similar databases.